# Flatten an array grouped by nested elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, nested

I have a tricky question... I have an array looks like this:

```js
[ 
  [ [ 'Attribute1', 'Attribute1Synonym1' ], [ 'Attribute2' ] ],
  [ [ 'Attribute3' ] ],
  [ [ 'Attribute2' ] ] 
]
```

My result should be:

```js
[
  'Attribute1 Attribute2',
  'Attribute1Synonym1 Attribute2',
  'Attribute3',
  'Attribute2'
]
```

The tricky thing is:

the result array has to grouped by the sub-sub-array

the crux is, the first index is an array(1) of arrays(2) of arrays(3) 
and i would to like flatten the array by level 3 (array(3)) and at the result should be every possible combination between the upper level.

At level 2 (the first index) is an array with ('Attribute1' and 'Attribute1Synonym1')
so the result should be:

'Attribute1 Attribute2'
and 
'Attribute1Synonym1 Attribute2'

the 'Attribute2' comes from the upper level

if the second index of level 2 ['Attribute2'] has also multiple indexes 
for example ['Attribute2Synonym5']
the result should be:

'Attribute1 Attribute2'
'Attribute1Synonym1 Attribute2'
'Attribute1 Attribute2Synonym5'
'Attribute1Synonym1 Attribute2Synonym5'

and so on...

Comment: You are right; that does seem kind of tricky, especially, when you don't share the rules of how it should be done. Also, it would be great if you could try and solve the problem yourself; you have tagged this with the `group-by` tag, so it seems like you have ideas of how it should be done. Please show your research and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works against your provided example, but I'm going to guess it's fragile against more complex arrays:

```
const deep = [ [ [ 'Attribute1', 'Attribute1Synonym1' ], [ 'Attribute2' ] ],
[ [ 'Attribute3' ] ],
[ [ 'Attribute2' ] ] ];
const flat = [];

deep.forEach(element => {
  const left = element[0];
  const right = element[1];
  left.forEach(leftElement => {
    if(right){
      right.forEach(rightElement => {
        flat.push(leftElement + ' ' + rightElement);
      });
    } else {
      flat.push(leftElement);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```js
var input_arr=[ [ [ 'Attribute1', 'Attribute1Synonym1' ], [ 'Attribute2' ] ],
  [ [ 'Attribute3' ] ],
  [ [ 'Attribute2' ] ] ];
var output_arr=[];
for(var key1 in input_arr){
 var sub_input_arr=input_arr[key1];
 for(var key2 in sub_input_arr){
  var sub_sub_input_arr=sub_input_arr[key2];
         for(var key3 in sub_sub_input_arr){
           output_arr.push(sub_sub_input_arr[key3]);
         }
 }
}
console.log(output_arr);
```